# Are custom tags possible in phpDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Does phpDoc support custom tags? I would like to use `@untested` to mark code that hasn't been tested yet. How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried searching in google? https://onomatopoeia.pinkgothic.com/article/extending-phpdocumentor-with-custom-tags

Comment: @rokas thanks for the 2009 article. Looks like phpDoc doesn't support the tags without going in and changing its code.

Comment: Meanwhile it seems to be possible.
Have a look at: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/ReflectionDocBlock/blob/master/examples/04-adding-your-own-tag.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use the [`@todo`](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/todo.html) tag like

```
 /**
  * Here comes the summary
  *
  * @todo this code has to be tested
  *
  * @return boolean Returns something
  */
 function someFunction()
 {
     <...>
 }
```

Or if you don't want this information to be included in your documentation, you could use the inline [`@internal`](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/internal.html) tag like this:

```
 /**
  * Here comes the summary
  *
  * {@internal this code has to be tested }}
  *
  * @return boolean Returns something
  */
 function someFunction()
 {
     <...>
 }
```

I don't think it is a good idea to add custom tags. Although PHPDoc is still informal, it is likely that it will become a formal standard in the near future. So if I were you, I'd stick with official tags whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, [PSR-5](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#531-tag-name) (still in draft as of May 2020) allows for custom tags *provided that you prefix them with a project or organization-specific name*:

> In support of annotations, it is allowable to introduce a set of tags designed specifically for an individual application or subset of applications (and thus not covered by this specification).
>
> These tags, or annotations, MUST provide a namespace by either
>
> prefixing the tag name with a PHP-style namespace, or by
>   prefixing the tag name with a single vendor-name followed by a hyphen.
>
> ...
>
> Example of a tag name prefixed with a vendor name and hyphen:
>
> `@phpdoc-event transformer.transform.pre`

So assuming PSR-5 is accepted, it seems like you'd be allowed to do something like `@myproject-untested`. There's no guarantee that the phpDoc tool will support a way to define these custom tags though, even if PSR-5 is accepted.